# Scrapy: Check if response is an image

Tags: image, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

> I need check if response is an image.

For requirements of the work I need to generate the url of the photos that can exist or no and record the url that contains an image.

When the url generated doesn't show a photo the response of the website is an html when the body is:

```
<body>No File Found</body>
```

also the `response.status =200`

The response header doesn't have a valuable info for both results with image and `No File Found`

```
For instance
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: AllowAll
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 01:44:40 GMT
```

The way that I found to check if the response is an image  for this case was:

```
        try :
            no_file_found = response.xpath("/html/body[contains(., 'No File Found')]")
        except:
            photo_url = response.url
            photo = PhotoItem()

            photo['id'] = id
            photo['url'] = photo_url

            yield photo
```

Because When the response is an image the line

```
no_file_found = response.xpath("/html/body[contains(., 'No File Found')]")
```

throw this exception:

```
raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
```

I know that this isn't an elegant solution , but for this context it works

**Question**

My question is If there is another way more elegant to solve this problem, that not use `try` to solve that.

Notice that I don't need to download the image just need to record the valid url

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to just check the type of the response:

```
from scrapy.http.response.text import TextResponse

if not isinstance(response, TextResponse):
    # it's probably an image; do image stuff
```